# Axios get passing header not working if use query param as second argument

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

I manage to use axios to do a GET request with header

```
fetchUsers = ({offset = 1, q = ''} = {}) => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

  const url = `localhost:3000/users`

  axios.get(url, {
    headers: { token: 123 }
  }).then(response => {

  })
})
```

But I also want optional query param for pagination and search, I do

```
fetchUsers = ({offset = 1, q = ''} = {}) => new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

  const url = `localhost:3000/users`

  axios.get(url, {params: {offset, q}}, {
    headers: { token: 123 }
  }).then(response => {

  })
})
```

I don't see my token in the header anymore, any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you should try to move your headers to object with params:

```
  axios.get(url, {params: {offset, q}, 
                  headers: { token: 123 }}
```